# aligning div by reference of a div

Tags: css, html

I m trying to align a div which is at the bottom of all the divs.

last div is floating div and align by css to top.

I don't know how to align it from the left hand side without any problem of the screen resolution change. If possible please tell me if I can give one div's id whose position is always fixed and left distance from that div with the help of css.

```
<div id='fixeddiv'>this div is at the top</div>
<div> rest of the divs </div>
<div> rest of the divs </div>
<div> rest of the divs </div>
<div> rest of the divs </div>
<div> rest of the divs </div>
<div> rest of the divs </div>
<div id='bottom_div'>this div is floating</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: could you be more specific i've hard time understanding what you want to achive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand you correctly and you want to give one left-alignment to the top and bottom divs and another to the rest of the divs, use classes:

```
<div id='fixeddiv' class='header-and-footer'>this div is at the top</div>
<div class='other-content'> rest of the divs </div>
<div class='other-content'> rest of the divs </div>
<div class='other-content'> rest of the divs </div>
<div class='other-content'> rest of the divs </div>
<div class='other-content'> rest of the divs </div>
<div class='other-content'> rest of the divs </div>
<div id='bottom_div' class='header-and-footer'>this div is floating</div>
```

css:

```
.header-and-footer {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.other-content { 
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

or:

```
div { 
    margin-left: 10px;
}

div.header-and-footer {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: in CSS I declared that div as left:0. and it's showing perfectly in firefox but in ie it's showing to the far left of the screen. What to do please reply

Comment: You should add the style `position: relative;` to the element containing your `div`. An absolutely positioned element will position relative to its closest parent with relative position.

Answer (score 0):

user jquery offset

```
http://api.jquery.com/offset/
```

and then

```
var offsetval=$('#relativediv').offset()

$('#bottom_div').css('left',offsetval.left);// change left value the way you want
```

Comment: Thanks for try, but it was only for html and css . no jquery